# Can we calculate $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m i!j!(i+j)! \bmod p$ faster than $O(p\log(p))$?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Suppose $p$ as a prime number. We want to calculate $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m i!j!(i+j)! \bmod p.$$If $i$ is larger or equal to $p$, $i!\equiv0\bmod p$. Thus, we should calculate only in the range $i+j < p$. Let $f(x):=\sum_{i=0}^{\min(n,p-1)} i!x^i, g(x):=\sum_{i=0}^{\min(m,p-1)} i!x^i, h(x):=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} i!x^i$. Then, what we want to calculate is equal to the constant term of $f(x)g(x)h(1/x)$. By using FFT(Fast Fourier Transform), we can calculate multiplication of polynomials in $O(p\log{p})$. Can we calculate faster than this? By using FFT and Lagrange interpolation, we can calculate $\sum_{i=1}^n i!$ in $O(\sqrt{p}\log{p})$ according to [1]. $\sum_{i=1}^ni!$ looks similar to $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mi!j!(i+j)!$, so I wonder if this method could be applicable or not. Any comment is welcomed. Thank you.

[1]:Alin Bostan, Pierrick Gaudry, and Eric Schost, Linear recurrences with polynomial coefficients and application to integer factorization and Cartier-Manin operator.

Comment: All terms where $(i+j)\ge p$ will have a factor of $p$ in the summand; such terms will be $\equiv 0 \bmod p$. In effect, the limits of summation must be chosen such that $n<p$ and $m\le p-n$

Comment: I change the time complexity of FFT according to your advice.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "FFT" - what is it?

Comment: FFT is Fast Fourier Transform.

Comment: I add explanation of why we can use FFT for the question. I'm sorry for the unclear explanation.